# "Deploy contract" dropdown menu not displaying in Ethereum Wallet

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

Why is the "deploy contract" dropdown menu not displaying in Ethereum Wallet for me?

I'm totally new to this. My new boss sent me info regarding the company launching an ICO soon and sent me a link to https://www.ethereum.org/token to read up on.

I am trying to follow the instructions but hitting a roadblock at the very beginning: Under the "Understanding the code section" on the linked tutorial there is a line that says

> Take a look at the right column besides the contract and you'll see a drop down, written pick a contract. Select the "MyToken" contract and you'll see that now it shows a section called Constructor parameters. These are changeable parameters for your token, so you can reuse the same code and only change these variables in the future.

And it shows this image: https://www.ethereum.org/images/tutorial/function-picker.png

However no such dropdown menu exists for me in Ethereum Wallet (I am using the newest version (Ethereum Wallet and Mist 0.9.3 "Cliente Ligero ") and it just shows this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaHvC.png

No dropdown but an "error":

```
 No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
function MyToken(){
^
Spanning multiple lines.
```

As you can see there is no dropdown and I have tried to change the visibility from default to public and it still shows an error but changes to: 
    Could not compile source code.

```
 Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
    public function MyToken(){
    ^
```

I appreciate any help I can get from you. Thanks and I look forward to joining the community here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put public in the function...

Example:

```
function MyToken() public {

...
}
```